# Trouble running a .mov file in processing 3

Tags: video, processing

I have this code written to display a movie in a new window in processing. When I run the code I get the display window, but nothing shows up inside it.

I've tried different movies and file types, different display sizes and frame rates with no luck. It recognizes the movie file in the data folder but says that it isn't available. I'm really new to this so it might have been a simple mistake

```
import processing.video.*; 

Movie movie; 

void setup() {  
  size (200, 200); 

  movie = new Movie(this, "test.mov");  
    print(movie.available());

}

void movieEvent(Movie M) {  
  M.read();
}

void draw() {
  image(movie, 0, 0);
}
```

I've also tried switching the draw and movieEvent sections with no luck. I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks correct. (Personally I would use upper case for classes only, (e.g. `movieEvent(Movie m)`, but doesn't change the way the code runs)

The one thing that appears missing is actually the `play()` or `loop()` call:

```
import processing.video.*; 

Movie movie; 

void setup() {  
  size (200, 200); 

  movie = new Movie(this, "test.mov");  
    print(movie.available());
  movie.loop();
}

void movieEvent(Movie ,) {  
  m.read();
}

void draw() {
  image(movie, 0, 0);
}
```

If the movie still doesn't play it might be worth doing a few more tests to isolate the issue: is it with the video file or video library on your system for some reason.

1. Open **Processing > Examples > Libraries > Video > Movie > Loop** and run it. If it plays it means the video library works fine on your system and it's likely the video file you use.
2. In your code, instead of "test.mov" try playing the transit video that comes with the video library examples. If that plays, tre encoding your video with the same codec (H.264) and try again.